# Syntax Error unexpected tANDOP on rails 3 Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error

I think i'm overlooking something stupid but i'm following a rails 3 tutorial, and I'm at the part where I'm adding errors if a user places a comment on an unpublished article...So in the rails console I try to create a comment on an "unpublished" article (a draft) by entering the following code

```
>> article = Article.draft.first
=> #<Article id: 7, title: "One-to-many associations",        ...> 
>> comment = article.comments.create :name => 'Dude', :email => 'dude@example.com', :body    => 'Great article!'
```

At this point it says i'm supposed to get the following:

```
=> #<Comment id: nil, article_id: 7, name: "Dude", email: "dude@example.com", body: "Great article!", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> >> comment.errors.full_messages => ["Article is not published yet"]
```

But instead I'm getting the following error:

SyntaxError: /Users/bbarton250/Sites/rails_projects/theoldman/app/models/comment.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tANDOP, expecting kEND
&& !article.published?
  ^
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in`load_file'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in`load_file'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in`load_missing_constant'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in`each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in`load_missing_constant'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in`each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:218:in`constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:217:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:217:in`constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:588:in`constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in `compute_type'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:109:in`each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:109:in `compute_type'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in`send'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:148:in`transaction'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:431:in `create_record'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:119:in`create'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `__send__'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in`create'

Here is my comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :email, :name, :article_id

  belongs_to :article

  validates :name, :email, :body, :presence => true
  validates :article_should_be_published

  def article_should_be_published
    errors.add(:article_id, "is not published yet") if article 
&& !article.published?
  end
end
```

Here is my article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :published_at, :title

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :body, :presence => true

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :comments

  scope :published, where("articles.published_at IS NOT NULL")
  scope :draft, where("articles.published_at IS NULL")
  # recent post from < a month ago - see pg 103 of tutorial
  # scope :recent, lambda { published.where("articles.published_at > ?", 1.month.ago.to_date)}
  scope :where_title, lambda { |term| where("articles.title LIKE ?", "%#{term}%") }

  def long_title
    "#{title} - #{published_at}"
  end

  def published?
    published_at.present?
  end
end
```

Please let me know if i need to provide anything else...I appreciate any and all help...Thanks so much

UPDATE:

After following iltempos tip...I am now getting the following validation error...

ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:86:in `validates'
    from /Users/bbarton250/Sites/rails_projects/theoldman/app/models/comment.rb:7
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in`load'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load_file'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in`new_constants_in'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in`require_or_load'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in`const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in`const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in`const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in`const_missing'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:218:in `constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:217:in`each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:217:in `constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in`get'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:588:in `constantize'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in`compute_type'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:109:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:109:in`compute_type'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `send'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in`klass'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:148:in `transaction'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:431:in`create_record'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:119:in `create'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in`**send**'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `create'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a line break where it should not be:

```
  def article_should_be_published
    errors.add(:article_id, "is not published yet") if article && !article.published?
  end
```

Comment: thanks iltempo...I'm getting the new error now though. i've included it above.  any idea about this "need to supply at least one validation" error.

Comment: Nevermind ilTempo...I used "validates:" when i should have been using "validate:"...thx for the help